# What are the rules of the yaml duration numerical format?

Tags: yaml

I just discovered what, for lack of a better word, I'm calling yaml's duration numerical format.

Take the following yaml

```yaml
value_1: 1:00:00
value_2: 01:00:00
```

My expectation would be that if this were to be converted to json it would be written as

```json
{
    "value_1": "1:00:00",
    "value_2": "01:00:00"
}
```

To my surprise though it is actually converted to

```json
{
    "value_1": 3600,
    "value_2": "01:00:00"
}
```

I observed this using both `pyyaml` and [an online yaml to json converter](https://jsonformatter.org/yaml-to-json)

I've done a quick search through the yaml spec and wasn't seeing this laid out as a supported numerical format, at least not in the terms I'd think to look for it. My speculation is that it is being interpreted as `hh:mm:ss` and converted into a count of seconds.

Is this part of the yaml specification or an extension within popular yaml implementations? If it is part of the specification what is the exact format supported?

Answer (score 4):

I reached out to the folks over at `pyyaml` and they were able to point me towards [the right place in the yaml spec](https://yaml.org/type/int.html). The format is called sexagesimal and has been [removed from Yaml v1.2](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/ext/changes/) however it looks like yaml v1.1 and prior are still pretty dominant. Taken from the v1.1 spec:

> Using “:” allows expressing integers in base 60, which is convenient for time and angle values.

The regex defining it is

```
[-+]?[1-9][0-9_]*(:[0-5]?[0-9])+
```

or for floats `[-+]?[0-9][0-9_]*(:[0-5]?[0-9])+\.[0-9_]*`